# How to add the es6 syntax to atom editor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

I was using sublime text, but now would like to use the atom.io editor. I have these lines of code:

```
// error: Missing semicolon.
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class RegisterName extends Component {
    constructor(props) {

        // error: Missing semicolon.
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            displayError: false,
            error: 'Please provide a valid name'

        //error: Missing semicolon.
        }
    }


    // error: Class property must be methods. Expected '(' but saw instead '='....
    next = () => {
        console.log('next')
        console.log(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.logoContainer}>
                        <Icon name="md-analytics" size={60} color="#2ec76e" />

                    // error: Unclosed regular expression
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Although this code is working fine. I'm getting these errors in atom.io editor. I have added the `.jshintrc` file, with these lines:

```
{
    "esnext": true
}
```

Also the grammar is set to: Babel E6 Javascript

But even this is not helping. How do I remove these errors?

Comment: I would consider switching from jshint to eslint. It has better support for es6 features

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon though... es6 syntax doesn't remove them... for e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: @azium Would you guide me how to? Thank you.

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra Oh! Sorry about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In your root directory, add a new file:

```
.jshintrc
```

Add the following code and save:

```
{
   "esversion": 6
}
```

You can find the settings in using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open the settings and go to `packages` => `linter-jshint` (or something like that) and find the pointer to the `.jshintrc` file. If the file in your project structure differs, you can change that here.

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me. Remove the semicolon for proper syntax.

Comment: Very good, nice simple fix, compared to the other answers. Just one thing: I think the trailing semicolon is illegal in `{
"esversion": 6;
}` so I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `npm install language-babel` in the terminal.
2. Restart Atom (if it's running)
3. Choose babel from the list of Editor Grammars (bottom-left side of the
   editor on the bar you should see the current syntax grammar being
   used, click on it and change it to babel)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can install ESLint with Atom and configure it to have ES6 syntax:

1. Install [Atom Linter](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter) if you  haven't already.
2. Install [linter-eslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint).
3. In your project directory, install eslint locally: `npm install eslint`
4. Again in your project directory, create an eslint config file (name it `.eslintrc`)

Here's an example `.eslintrc` from the [eslint website](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)—see below if you want to use the Airbnb styleguide:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [Airbnb ES6 styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/).

1. Install it via npm: `npm install eslint-config-airbnb`.
2. Put this in your `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not helping.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. From my understading, either babel, es6, react should show up in the list of grammars, which don't.

Comment: What if I don't want to follow a styleguide, but only want syntax errors?