# How to add ES6 to Atom grammar

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

How can I add ES6 to the list of supported grammars by Atom ?

I already tried answers by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898538/how-to-add-the-es6-syntax-to-atom-editor), which didn't work.

I tried `apm install language-babel`, but nothing related to bable shows up in the list of grammars of Atom.

Comment: I'm using language-babel as well, and if I have a JS file opened and do a `Select Grammar` I do have a `Babel ES6 Javascript` option (which is already selected). I'm running language-babel 2.75.1.

Comment: Yep, I had to restart atom to make it take effect.